# Mouse events not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, events, mobile, three.js, touch

I created this [360 panorama image](https://jsfiddle.net/78r60zar/4/) which is working fine in desktop but on mobile phones the mouse events are not working. How can i fix this for mobile?

// listeners

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", onDocumentMouseDown, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", onDocumentMouseMove, false);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", onDocumentMouseUp, false);
```

I change the events to

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", onDocumentMouseDown, false);
document.addEventListener("touchmove", onDocumentMouseMove, false);
document.addEventListener("touchend", onDocumentMouseUp, false);
```

but this is not working for mobile.

Comment: have you wrote your code within deviceready function?

Comment: i just added tounch events in the mouse events. What is a deviceready functions?

Comment: Can you please explain further what exactly is not working. Usually touch events work on mobiles (Android, Safari, etc). You can also use `touchleave` because touch event behavior is not uniform among variety of mobile browsers.

Comment: @domino_katrino can you please check the fiddler example i posted in my question. If you move mouse over the image then you will see mouse effects but when i am trying this on mobile the events are not working

Comment: This event is essential to any application. It signals that Cordova's device APIs have loaded and are ready to access. kindly check the answer below.

Comment: again @PriyaRajaram i want to clear you this is not a phonegap app it will be running on mobile webs

Comment: @OwaisAhmed - you have not added listeners to touch events in your fiddle.

Comment: yes he updated one is this https://jsfiddle.net/78r60zar/8/ . In the question i am saying if i replace the mouse events with the touch events its still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer. For touch event.clientX and event.clientY were not working which i have changed to event.touches[0].clientX and event.touches[0].clientY and it fixed the touch event issue.

Answer (score 1):

for mobiles, try like this. you have to use deviceready function for initiation.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);

function init() {   
    document.querySelector("#yourbuttonId").addEventListener("touchstart", onDocumentMouseDown, false)
}
```

This event is essential to any application. It signals that Cordova's device APIs have loaded and are ready to access.

Cordova consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the native code loads, a custom loading image displays. However, JavaScript only loads once the DOM loads. This means the web app may potentially call a Cordova JavaScript function before the corresponding native code becomes available.

The deviceready event fires once Cordova has fully loaded. Once the event fires, you can safely make calls to Cordova APIs. Applications typically attach an event listener with document.addEventListener once the HTML document's DOM has loaded.

The deviceready event behaves somewhat differently from others. Any event handler registered after the deviceready event fires has its callback function called immediately.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

read this link.

thanks.

Comment: thanks priya but this is not what i want i already created events for mobile and they are not working properly

Comment: and this is not a phonegap app i will be running this on mobile web so javascript will be working normally on mobile DOM i think you misunderstood my question

Comment: you have created init event to call mouseevents. I am doing the same without creating any init methods. I tried this and not working