# Three.js OnDocumentMouseDown does not work with touch screen?

Tags: javascript, three.js, touch, augmented-reality, aframe

Full code in this Glitch project. https://glitch.com/~quickest-catshark

I have declared a custom AFRAME component in `public/components.js` that rotates the item when dragging with mouse.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('drag-rotate-component', {
    schema: { speed: { default: 10 } },
    init: function () {
        this.ifMouseDown = false;
        this.x_cord = 0;
        this.y_cord = 0;
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.OnDocumentMouseDown.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.OnDocumentMouseUp.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.OnDocumentMouseMove.bind(this));
    },
    // When mouse down, save x and y coordinates of mouse position
    OnDocumentMouseDown: function (event) {
        this.ifMouseDown = true;
        this.x_cord = event.clientX;
        this.y_cord = event.clientY;
    },
    OnDocumentMouseUp: function () {
        this.ifMouseDown = false;

        // Save rotation to localstorage
        let rotation = this.el.object3D.rotation.z;
        localStorage.setItem('angle', rotation);
    },
    OnDocumentMouseMove: function (event) {
        if (this.ifMouseDown) {
            // Get difference between current mouse position and previous mouse position
            var temp_x = event.clientX - this.x_cord;
            var temp_y = event.clientY - this.y_cord;

            this.el.object3D.rotation.z = temp_x * this.data.speed / 1000;
        }
    }
});
```

The code works as intended in the browser.

But when I access it from Chrome in my mobile phone, nothing happens when I drag my finger in the area. Doesn't work in my Surface Pro touch tablet either.

How do I get it to work in touch devices?

I tried the answe given in this question 
[Mouse events not working in mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081238/mouse-events-not-working-in-mobile)

Use `event.touches[0].clientX` and `event.touches[0].clientY`. But these return undefined.

Comment: touch screen doesn't provide with mouse events.
So you should use touch events (**touchstart, touchmove and touchend**).

Comment: otherwise, you may use pointerevents **(pointerdown, pointerup and pointermove)**
And this way worked on mobile device

Comment: Thank you!! I used touchstart, touchmove and touchend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend` for touch and in those events you'd use `event.touches[0].clientX` and `clientY`

Further, you want probably want your event handlers to not be passive so that in touchstart you can tell the browser to ignore the touch otherwise the page will scroll/zoom/etc...

You can find an example here

[Supporting Touch Interface in a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908313/supporting-touch-interface-in-a-canvas/58908864#58908864)